# Function return string or undefined, typescript no error tips

Tags: typescript, function, undefined, tslint

Code just like this:

```
const getInfo = (): string | undefined => {
  if (Math.random() <= 0.5) {
    return '';
  }
  return undefined;
};

const info = getInfo();

info.slice();
```

info could be `string` or `undefined`, but there is no any tips.

[image]

typescript@4.4.2

Comment: [I'm unable to reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygSTAMxDAvDAFASgC4ZoAnASzDhgB8YBXMAEwTUoSewD4YBvAWABQMGOTR4AsgEMoACwB0pKcxABbAjAA8OAAzyArPj5CRI0knqkwMAOQ2A3CZgBfJ+aiXrjFmzAdHgs4BQqCQsJQY2PBIqBgEwYIRIPIQADbkwAjxQA). It warns about the possible undefined.

Comment: you can use snippets for those questions https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/typescript

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Check [strictNullChecks documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks). By default strictNullChecks is set to `false` and therefore compiler does not raise any error regarding possibly undefined values. Add `strictNullChecks` to your `tsconfig.json` and you will get "Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)" error.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```